# Installing visual studio community won't change the installation directory

Tags: visual-studio, installation, installation-path

I just downloaded  Visual Studio 2017 community and tried to install it but when I did I made directory `D: separate from main directory C:`

Everything I had in installation had message not enough space even tho i have around `300GB free space in D: and around 50GB in C:`

Installationg has around 50GB and it is showing me the C: drive memory with that message that I don't have enough space even tho it is changed to be installed into drive D:

Here is an screen shot of installation:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

When we choose another drive to install VS, it still requires the space on the system drive, please have a look at this: [Why Visual Studio 11 Requires Space on the System Drive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2012/03/07/why-visual-studio-11-requires-space-on-the-system-drive/), because the shared components, packages and Windows Installer and package caches still need to install on the system drive.

From the screenshot, it looks like you choose all workloads or most of them, it is huge and usually we can select the needed workloads per your development requirement, you can refer to [Visual Studio Community 2017 workload and component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community) to know the detail description of those workloads, then uncheck some workloads to make it small.

After the initial installation, we still can modify it to install more workloads through run this installer and click the icon beside ‘Launch button, choose ‘Modify’ to select more workloads or individual components to install.

Comment: Thanks but I installed all on C and moved all to D and it works :D

Comment: @NoNameNeedToKnow, do you mean the installation is successful now? If so, I'm so glad to hear that and please add a reply with your solution, it will help other community members, thanks.